# How do i allow all visitors to see my sharepoint site

Tags: permissions

I have created a site and I want visitors to be able to read everything on the site (default setting). How do i achieve that?

Comment: Activate Anonymous Access: http://www.dynamics101.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2010-enable-anonymous-access/

Answer (score 1):

This is called Anonymous access. Here si a guide to enable it for Sharepoint 2010: http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010

There is tons of other material about this on the web, just search for "Anonymous access Sharepoint"